# Need Regex expression for SQL object names

Tags: sql, regex

I have a lot of SQL scripts whith DDL and DML statements.

I want to segregate and extract modified/created/dropped SQL objects.
I. e., i have a script:

```
  create proc [dbo].test
  as
     print 1
  go

  drop table test_table
  go

  alter procedure dbo.test
  as
     print 2
```

I have to get created/changed/dropped SQL objects, e. g. like the following:

- proc dbo.test - create
- table test_table - drop
- proc dbo.test - alter

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from the question that where will you be using the regex but try this:

```
/(create)(.*)|(drop)(.*)|(alter)(.*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse arbitrary sql server stored procedures, you're far better off with a SQL parser. Trying to parse arbitrary SQL with regexes will amount to writing your own parser.

With the help of a full [SQL Parser](http://www.sqlparser.com), demo from [this page](http://sqlparser.com/features/crud-reportor.php) generates result like this which is exactly what you need:

```
sstMssqlCreateProcedure(proc: [dbo].test - create)
sstMssqlPrint
sstMssqlGo
sstMssqlDropTabletable: test_table - drop
sstMssqlGo
sstMssqlAlterProcedure(proc: dbo.test - alter)
sstMssqlPrint
```